# Merge two tables in PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-merge

I have next 3 tables:

- Fibonacci(id, value) first 1000 fibonacci numbers.
- Prime(id, value) first 2000 prime numbers.
- FiboPrime(value, prime), initially the table is empty.

I have to populate the FiboPrime table, with the prime numbers from Fibonacci table (prime=1 => the number is prime, else the number is not prime.)

I have to use MERGE statement and it is attempt:

```
DECLARE

    BEGING
        MERGE INTO FiboPrime fp
         USING fibonacci f, prime p
         ON (f.value=p.value)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET
          fp.value=f.value,
          fp.prime=1;
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT VALUES(f.value,0);
END;
```

I get the next error: Econtered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:
:= .( @ ; not null range character. Who can help me to solve it?

Comment: You have an extra semicolon here: `fp.prime=1;`. The entire `MERGE` should have but one semicolon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> DECLARE
>
> BEGING

1. You don't need the keyword `DECLARE`, since you don't have anything to declare.
2. The keyword is `BEGIN` and **NOT BEGING**.
3. Modify the `USING` clause to a `SELECT` query. For example:

`USING (select t1.col1,t2.col2 from t1,t2)`

4. I don't see there is any reason to do it in **PL/SQL**. Execute the `MERGE` as SQL. No need of wrapping it with `BEGIN-END` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
MERGE INTO FiboPrime fp
         USING ( select Fibonacci.value f, Prime.value p from Fibonacci, prime ) t
         ON (t.f = t.p)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET
          fp.value=t.f,
          fp.prime=1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT  VALUES(t.f,0);
```